# tmux prompt misaligned in intellij terminal window

Tags: command-line, tmux, prompt, intellij-idea

[image]

Why is it misaligned? I also see that tmux is not honoring `set -g default-shell "/bin/bash"`
or `set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l bash"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug, which is currently being tracked on [GitHub](https://github.com/JetBrains/jediterm/issues/148) and [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-229458).

Answer (score 1):

as found in the issue mentioned previously by @eyqs,

```
:set status-position top
```

solved the bug for me